# Web API Routing changes after DB Refresh

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

This is an exceedingly strange problem and I'm only including it as an oddity in case someone's seen it before.

I am on C#, ASP.Net web api, Fluent Nhibernate and SQL Server 2012

I have a Meal object that I pass to a web api controller method :

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("PostMeal")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostMeal(Meal mealToPost)
{
var helper = new Datahelper();
try
        {
            var fshelper = new FoodServiceHelper(helper);
            fshelper.SaveMeal(mealToPost);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, ex);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

The method that posts is similarly very simple:

```
public void SaveMeal(Meal mealToPost)
{
        var url = _connectionString + "food/PostMeal";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
        {
            SerializerSettings = { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }
        };
        var clientTask = client.PostAsync(url, mealToPost, formatter)
             .ContinueWith(posttask => posttask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());
clientTask.wait();
}
```

The meal object is pretty straightforward. Some elementaries, some generic collections.

I am able to post normally for several (usually about 20) meals, at which point it is somehow no longer able to find the route. I verified this by adding breakpoints to the server side. It hits it the first several times, then it won't even find the controller method.

Here's the weird part. If I drop and recreate the database, it's ok again for another 20 or so meals.

I suspect that this is some kind of mapping issue, but I cannot prove it.

Curious.

Comment: The first thing I can I think of is to ensure that the POST Call is happening and in addition, it is mapping the parameters from Body (not from header or URLP) - So you should change the public HttpResponseMessage PostMeal([FromBody] Meal mealToPost)

Comment: You can check with fiddler or Google dev tool and see the exactly response. Then you can post the same here.